# Post entity returning null for testresttemplate

Tags: resttemplate, spring-boot-test

I am doing my integration test using test rest template but for postForEntity method I am getting null as response body, but I saw examples which were working fine on that but I am unable to resolve my issue,

PFB my test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PersonControllerTests {

    
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @MockBean
    private PersonRepository mockRepository;
    
    @Before
    public void init() {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Person p1 = new Person("dumm1", "lastName1",22);
        Person p2 = new Person("dumm2", "lastName2",32);
        p1.setId(1l);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(p1);
        when(mockRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(list);
        when(mockRepository.findById(1l)).thenReturn(Optional.of( p1 ));
    }

    
    @Test
    public void createPerson() throws Exception {
    Person  p = new Person("dummy1", "dumm2", 11);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Person> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Person>(p,headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
            .withBasicAuth("user", "password")
            
            .postForEntity("/persons/create", httpEntity, String.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    //assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, response.getHeaders().getContentType());
    assertEquals(11, response.getBody());
    }
```

PFB my original code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Person> getAllUser() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value ="/create",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Person createUser( @RequestBody Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }
}
```

I believe I am doing some silly mistake but unable to understand

Comment: There is nothing about Spring Integration in your question: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration. Please , be careful when you chose tags for your questions. Doesn’t look like you mock that `save()` on your repository

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@MockBean` for your `PersonRepository`. Without any stubbing setup, Mockito returns `null` for reference types.

That's why `return personRepository.save(person);` returns `null` during your test.

You can stub your mock to simulate its behavior:

```
// import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

when(personRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.any(Person.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
  Person person = invocation.getArgument(0);
  // I assume you have an id field
  person.setId(42L);
  return person;
});
```

Comment: giving me this compilation error **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Matcher<Person> to S** I have CrudRepository<Person,Long>  like this

Comment: are you using Mockito's `ArgumentMatchers.any()` ?

Comment: import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.any; this one got imported

Comment: that's the wrong one. Try it with the `import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;`